# Cambiar un diccionario específico, Complejo

Tags: python, funciones, diccionarios

**Necesito cambiar un diccionario cuando sea igual a un texto no se como hacerlo.**
Existen dos diccionarios que almacenan diccionarios.

```
conceptos_de_mi={}
sobre_ti={}
```

se componen de esta forma:
{'Yo': {'soy': {'Lola': {}}}}

Existe un nombre.

```
tunombre="Carlos"
```

Se envia el texto a la funcion y se crea el diccionario

```
aprender("Yo soy Lola")
```

***Este código recibe el texto que crea diccionarios dentro de un diccionario.***

```
def aprender(oraciones):
#enviar_palabras=oraciones
recordar_pal = sobre_ti
for palabra in oraciones.split(): #dividir palabras para rellenar diccionarios

    if palabra not in recordar_pal: #si la primera palabra no esta en el diccionario principal
        recordar_pal[palabra] = {}  #añadir palabra
    recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra] #guardar posicion dentro del subdicionario

return aprender_conceptos_mi(oraciones) #llamar funcion intercambio
```

Luego envía el texto a esta otra función que se supone que debe cambiar un diccionario en especifico de nombre Lola por Carlos pero no lo hace, (cambiar un diccionario en especifico no todos) ya he intentado de muchas formas y no logro conseguirlo.

```
def aprender_conceptos_mi(enviar_palabras):
recordar_pals=conceptos_de_mi
sunombres=tunombre
#recordar_sobre_ti=sobre_ti
for palabra in enviar_palabras.split():
    if palabra not in recordar_pals:
        recordar_pals[palabra] = {}
        if palabra == sunombres:
            recordar_pals[palabra] = recordar_pals[sunombres]
            
    else:
        pass
       
    recordar_pals = recordar_pals[palabra]
```

Creando otro ejemplo de funcion fallido.

```
tunombre="Lola"
sunombre="Carlos"
def aprender(oraciones):
    sobre_ti_dic = sobre_ti
    tunombres=tunombre  
    sunombres=sunombre
    recordar_pal = sobre_ti
    recordar_pals = conceptos_de_mi
    for palabra in oraciones.split(): #dividir palabras para rellenar diccionarios

        if palabra not in recordar_pal: #si la primera palabra no esta en el diccionario principal
            recordar_pal[palabra] = {}  #añadir palabra
        #guardar posicion dentro del subdicionario
        if palabra not in sobre_ti_dic:
            sobre_ti_dic[palabra] = {}
        if tunombres in sobre_ti_dic[tunombres]:
            recordar_pals[palabra] = sobre_ti_dic[sunombres]
            print("Cambiando nombre")
        else:
            print("Palabra no esta en sobre ti")
        sobre_ti_dic = sobre_ti_dic[palabra]
        recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra]
    return
```

El diccionario por default es

```
{'yo': {'soy': {'Lola':{} }}    
}
```

El diccionario de salida

```
{'yo': {'soy': {'Carlos':{} }}    
}
```

Comment: ¿Que debo hacer si mi comentario queda en el olvido? ojala me ayuden, no importa lo que haga no me sale lo que quiero.

Comment: No se entiende a qué te refieres con eso de "cambiar un diccionario". Creo que sería más claro si pones un ejemplo con un diccionario de entrada (por ejemplo el de Lola, quizás más complejo) y después el diccionario que querrías obtener como resultado.

Comment: @abulafia Hola Abulafia, tratare de explicarlo de nuevo, existen dos diccionarios que contienen diccionarios anidados como la vez anterior, Yo}soy}Lola}} o imaginalo como A}B}C} ambos diccionarios tiene lo mismo pero solo uno sera cambiado, mi objetivo es cambiar {Lola} del diccionario (conceptos_de_mi) por el nombre guardado en la variable (tunombre), osea cambiar Lola por Carlos, espero que me hallas entendido, no sabría explicarlo mejor.

Comment: @abulafia Añadi otra funcion en la que he fracasado, para ver si entiendes mejor, creo que en esta puedes entender un poco lo que busco, tal vez.

Comment: Buenas, no entiendo mucho, quieres cambiar de un diccionario por ejemplo {'A': {'B': {'C': {}}}} a otro que dado el valor a cambiar (por ejemplo B) y el valor a poner(por ejemplo D) de como resultado {'A': {'D': {'C': {}}}} ??

Comment: @JavideSs Si, en efecto, tomando en cuenta que es un texto que se convertira en diccionario, osea D es un texto que cambiara B que sera un diccionario.

Comment: @Lolita Pues sigo sin entenderlo, sobre todo porque dices que esa función no hace lo que querías así que ¿cómo voy a adivinar lo que querías mirando una función que no lo hace bien? :-) Creo que es más fácil lo que te pedía antes. Pon un ejemplo del diccionario de entrada, y otro de cómo quieres que quede el diccionario de salida, dada una cierta secuencia de letras como "frase"

Comment: @abulafia Añadi como quedaria el diccionario al final de la pregunta, osea el mismo diccionario solo cambiaria un diccionario interno el diccionario llamado Lola, el cambio de Lola por Carlos deberia efectuarse si en el diccionario Lola es igual a Lola entonces cambiar por Carlos, perdoname sino me se explicar es que soy nueva en esto.

Comment: Entonces, primero introduces el texto "Yo soy Lola" y eso genera el primer diccionario. Y luego quieres que si se introduce el texto "Yo soy Carlos" se sustituya en el primer diccionario la palabra "Lola" por "Carlos"? Y si se introduce por ejemplo "Yo no soy Carlos", en ese caso se anidaría dentro del primero para dar algo como `{"yo": { "soy": { "Lola": {}}}, "no": {"soy": {"Carlos": {}}}}` ?

Comment: Si, exacto, en caso de a ver ingresado "Yo no soy Carlos" se anidaria como tu dices.

Comment: @Lolita Veo que no me acercaba con mi respuesta ni por asombro a lo que pedías xd, la he eliminado, la respuesta de abulafia parece correcta

Comment: @JavideSs Gracias por tu ayuda, aunque no debiste borrarla, mirando tu corrección pude a ver aprendido algo y tal vez me hubiera ayudado en el futuro con otras cosas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vamos a ver si lo he entendido. El usuario introduce frases que son convertidas en diccionarios anidados que de alguna forma registran el orden en que aparecieron las palabras en la frase. Según se van introduciendo frases que comienzan por las mismas palabras, la estructura de diccionarios anidados va creando una especie de árbol. Por ejemplo:

```
aprender("Yo soy Lola")
aprender("Yo estoy contenta")
aprender("Yo estoy aprendiendo")
```

genera un diccionario anidado:

```
{'Yo': {'soy': {'Lola': {}}, 'estoy': {'contenta': {}, 'aprendiendo': {}}}}
```

que en el fondo refleja el árbol:

```
Yo ---> soy   ---> Lola
   \--> estoy ---> contenta
              \--> aprendiendo
```

Eso es lo que hace tu función `aprender()`.

Lo que ahora quieres es que si el usuario introduce otra frase se añada al diccionario anterior, pero con una variante. Si el usuario introdujera ahora "Yo soy Carlos Lopez", con la función `aprender()` anterior "Carlos" se añadiría al mismo nivel que "Lola" y el árbol resultante sería:

```
Yo ---> soy -----> Lola
  |         \----> Carlos  --> Lopez
   \--> estoy ---> contenta
              \--> aprendiendo
```

Pero tú no quieres esto. Quieres que si, según se va analizando la frase y se va recorriendo el árbol se alcanza un lugar donde la palabra era "Lola", entonces que todo lo que sigue después en la frase **sustituya** a lo que había en el árbol original. Es decir, quieres que el árbol resultante sea este:

```
Yo ---> soy   ---> Carlos   ---> Lopez
   \--> estoy ---> contenta
              \--> aprendiendo
```

### Respuesta

Si es esto lo que estabas preguntando, creo que la siguiente función haría lo que pides:

```
def aprender_con_reemplazo(oracion, reemplazar):
  recordar_pal = sobre_ti
  for palabra in oracion.split():
      if reemplazar in recordar_pal:
        del recordar_pal[reemplazar]
      if palabra not in recordar_pal:
         recordar_pal[palabra] = {}
      recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra]
```

Esta función recibe además de la frase que se va a analizar, el argumento `reemplazar` que en nuestro ejemplo sería la palabra  `"Lola"`. Observa que si encontramos esa palabra en el nivel del diccionario que toque procesar, **eliminamos esa clave**, y por tanto todo el sub-árbol que contenía. El resto de la función es igual, por lo que la clave `"Carlos"` se insertará en ese punto, con el resultado de que "Lola" ha desaparecido y "Carlos" ha aparecido, por lo que es como si se hubiera sustituído uno por otro.

### Ejemplos demostrativos

Veamos un ejemplo de uso y el resultado obtenido:

```
sobre_ti={}
aprender("Yo soy Lola")   # <--- Esta era tu función de aprender normal
aprender("Yo estoy contenta")
aprender("Yo estoy aprendiendo")
print(sobre_ti)
aprender_con_reemplazo("Yo soy Carlos Lopez", "Lola") # <--- Esta es la mia
print(sobre_ti)
```

El resultado que sale del primer `print()` es:

```
{'Yo': {'soy': {'Lola': {}},
        'estoy': {'contenta': {},
                  'aprendiendo': {}}}}
```

Y en el segundo `print()`:

```
{'Yo': {'soy': {'Carlos': {'Lopez': {}}}, 
        'estoy': {'contenta': {}, 
                  'aprendiendo': {}}}}
```

Observa que ante frases que no tengan "Lola" en el lugar apropiado, no se produce esta sustitución, sino que se "aprende" de la forma habitual. Por ejemplo:

```
sobre_ti={}
aprender("Yo soy Lola")
aprender_con_reemplazo("Yo era Carlos", "Lola")
print(sobre_ti)
```

```
{'Yo': {'soy': {'Lola': {}}, 
        'era': {'Carlos': {}}}}
```

Supongo que esto era lo que esperabas. No me queda claro sin embargo para qué el otro diccionario `conceptos_de_mi`.

## Actualización

En un comentario la OP indica que no quiere que se sustituya el árbol completo por debajo de "Lola", como yo había entendido, sino solo la palabra "Lola".

Es decir, entiendo que si el árbol de entrada es:

```
Yo ---> soy ---> Lola ---> que ---> tal
           \---> Maria --> hola
```

Y se registra la frase "Yo soy Carlos", con `reemplazar="Lola"` se debe reemplazar únicamente la palabra "Lola" por "Carlos", respetando el resto del árbol. Y en este caso la salida debería ser:

```
Yo ---> soy ---> Carlos--> que ---> tal
           \---> Maria --> hola
```

Este caso también es relativamente sencillo. Pero hay un problema. Podría parecer que se tratara simplemente de reemplazar la clave "Lola" por la clave "Carlos", pero eso no se puede hacer. Las claves de un diccionario son inmutables. Lo que sí se puede hacer es insertar una clave nueva "Carlos", ponerle como valor lo que antes tenía la clave "Lola", y después eliminar la clave "Lola".

Así:

```
def aprender_con_reemplazo(oracion, buscar):
  recordar_pal = sobre_ti
  for palabra in oracion.split():
      if buscar in recordar_pal:
        recordar_pal[palabra] = recordar_pal[buscar]  # <--- Añadido esto
        del recordar_pal[buscar]
      if palabra not in recordar_pal:
         recordar_pal[palabra] = {}
      recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra]
```

Demo:

```
sobre_ti={}
aprender("Yo soy Lola que tal")
aprender("Yo soy Maria hola")
aprender_con_reemplazo("Yo soy Carlos", "Lola")
print(sobre_ti)
```

Resultado:

```
{'Yo': {'soy': {'Maria': {'hola': {}}, 
                'Carlos': {'que': {'tal': {}}}}}
}
```

Comment: Dios mio lo haces parecer tan simple, es justamente lo que quería hacer, exactamente lo que he estado intentando, pero existe un pequeño problemita y es aqui-->   aprender_con_reemplazo("Yo era Carlos", "Lola") pues esta palabra "Lola" es fija, intente cambiar por una variable que almacena los nombres a cambiar llamada (sunombre="Lola") pero no me funciono, hice lo siguiente                        -->   aprender_con_reemplazo("Yo era Carlos", sunombre) y fracase.

Comment: No lo entiendo. No necesitas tocar la función, para eso recibe un parámetro. Si quieres puedes tener una variable exterior a la función `sunombre="Lola"` y después pasarla como parámetro `aprender_con_reemplazo("Yo era Carlos", sunombre)` y debería funcionar. Observa sin embargo que "Yo era Carlos" es el ejemplo en el que no se produce sustitución, pues la frase contenida en el diccionario era "Yo soy Lola". Prueba con `aprender_con_reemplazo("Yo soy Carlos", sunombre)`

Comment: Esta bien, disculpa, es que puse llamar la función por encima de la variable, por eso no me habia funcionado, ya funciona con lo que me dijiste, pero ahora me enfrento a otro problema y es que si Lola esta en el primer nivel del arbol, al hacer el cambio, todo el arbol se elimina y no se lleva a cabo el remplazo.

Comment: Bueno, entiendo como funciona el codigo que has hecho pero lo que hace es eliminar el diccionario con todos los subdiccionarios consigo, y pues eso no deberia pasar, cuando cambie Lola a Carlos, Carlos deberia tener todos los subdiccionarios de Lola.

Comment: @Lolita Creo que entiendo. Por eso te pedía que pusieras ejemplos más complejos para poder entender exactamente lo que te propones. He extendido la respuesta con una explicación de lo que creo que pretendes, y una modificación a la función para que haga eso. Aún me queda la duda de si al final lo que quieres es cambiar "Lola" por "Carlos" en todas partes del árbol, aparezca donde aparezca, o si está bien como hice, que sólo lo cambie si su posición en la frase analizada coincide.

Comment: @Oh wau, ¿porque no se me ocurrio eso? me complico tanto buscando una solucion y tu pues, de una vez la tienes, eres muy bueno, ahora si hace lo que buscaba, pero hay un ligero problemita otra vez, y es que si el diccionario que se cambiara es de primer nivel ejemplo Lola-->debe-->aprender-->mas   entonces todo los sub diccionarios se borran y no ocurre el reemplazo, no entiendo, se supone que debería funcionar, sospecho que los de primer nivel no son diccionarios.

Comment: Hola? bueno si no se puede solucionar el problema que te explique anteriormente respondeme para dejar como valida tu respuesta, despues de todo funciona una parte de ella.

Comment: @Lolita El problema es que aún no está claro lo que estás buscando, por eso tantas vueltas. Si el arbol comienza siendo "Lola --> debe --> aprender", y se llama a `aprender_con_reemplazo("Carlos está aprendiendo", "Lola")` el resultado que da mi función es `{'Carlos': {'debe': {'aprender': {}}, 'está': {'aprendiendo': {}}}}`, que me parece correcto de acuerdo con lo que entendí hasta aqui. Por otro lado creo que esta pregunta/respuesta ha crecido ya demasiado. Te propongo cerrarla aqui y que abras una nueva (puedes incluir un enlace a esta), explicando el caso en que no sale lo que quieres.

Comment: Bien, hare asi para explicar el problema en otro tema.